# Getting Element index in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

Referring to the to do example [here](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/remove-elements/), I wanted to get the clicked element index, so I wrote the below, and it worked fine, I need to know is this the correct way, or there is a short cut for that.

```dart
void addToDoItem(Event e) {
     var newToDo = new LIElement(); 
     toDoList.children.add(newToDo);

     var index = newToDo.parent.children.indexOf(newToDo);

     newToDo.text = toDoInput.value;
     newToDo.onClick.listen((e) => print(index));
     toDoInput.value = '';
 }
```

Comment: If it works. The cold could be made a bit shorter maybe but otherwise it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
void addToDoItem(Event e) {
  var newToDo = new LIElement()
      ..text = toDoInput.value;
  toDoList.children.add(newToDo);
  newToDo.onClick.listen((e) => print(newToDo.parent.children.indexOf(newToDo));
  toDoInput.value = '';
}
```

Comment: this gave me [undefined name 'parent']